# How to distinguish rows from each other in a database table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have some records that I need to store in a database table and I want to distinguish one record from other records on the basis of `name` field.

But as the datatype of name field is `varchar`, it will effect the performance because comparing `varchar` data with each other is time consuming process in comparision to a numeric field.

So I want each record to have a unique numeric field (say `id`). But if I make the `id` as primary key, then the more than one record can contain same `name`.

What's the solution to the above problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still create a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `name` field:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE (name);
```

The `UNIQUE` constraint, like the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, will guarantee that your column will contain only unique values.

Note that you can have many `UNIQUE` constraints per table, but only one `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

Comment: Could you please look at the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301691/what-datatype-to-use-for-a-field-that-can-contain-a-value-from-pre-defined-values

Answer (score 0):

Name can be made unique index.