# Database Table design problem

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

`Scenario:`
There is a hierarchy of `PROCESS`. Like

`PR-2, PR-3 are children of Pr-1`,

`PR-4, PR-5 are children of PR-2`

Now the `leaf processes (in our case PR-3, PR-4 and PR-5` can be described in terms of series of `ACTIVITY`

Now, `ACTIVITY` is just a child of `PROCESS` but has some extra attributes, so

Should I make two diff. tables in the database (one for `ACTIVITY` and one for `PROCESS`)?

or

Should I add some fields (for extra attributes of `ACTIVITIY`) in the `PROCESS` table and store the `ACTIVITY` in `PROCESS` table.

=================================== EDITED ======================================

Actually, here `PROCESS` AND `ACTIVITY` are the one's that involved in BPM (Businees Process Management)

Those who have knowledge of BPM can figure out what `ACTIVITY` AND `PROCESS` are.

Those who don't know `BPM`, I explain you what I mean by `PROCESS` and `ACTIVITY`.

Any enterprise has various `PROCESS`es (like CustomerOrderPlaced, CustomerOrderCancelled etc.) and `ACTIVIT`ies are like parts of a process which are to be performed to complete the process.

So, `ACTIVITY` is a child of `PROCESS` with some extra attributes.

Or in terms of Java, ACTIVITY extends PROCESS

Comment: This looks like a classical 1:n relationship to me (every PROCESS can have n number of ACTIVITIES). In that case, they should be in separate tables.

Comment: @Pekka I have posted another question which is much clear that this question. The question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301841/should-there-be-2-datatables-for-a-parent-and-child-class-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you say "`ACTIVITY` are like *parts* of a process", "`ACTIVITY` extends `PROCESS`" is no longer a valid statement. It's not an is-a relationship. It's a has-a relationship.

In ER terms there is a one-to-many relationship between Process and Activity. Or possibly a many-to-many relationship if one Activity belongs to multiple Processes.

For example, CustomerPlacesOrder is a Process. The Activities are:

- Customer fills shopping Cart;
- Customer checks out;
- Customer enters delivery and billing info, registering if necessary;
- Worker receives order;
- If the items are in stock, the Worker selects an appropriate packing container and fills it;
- Worker send it on the daily deliveries.

Or however complicated you want to get. Inheritance this is not.

Comment: +1 ... First a very thanks to clear the point.. Actually, I was confused between which relationship they have (is-a or has-a).. And I appreciate your understanding of what I wanted to explain.. Great answer...

Answer (score 0):

You should have multiple tables. The tables can be like below:

> ### ProcessTable
>
> **ID** (Primary Key)
>   **ProcessName**
>   **ProcessCode**
>   ...
>
> ### ActivityTable
>
> **ID** (Primary Key)
>   **ActivityName**
>   **ActivityCode**
>   **ActivityDesc**
>   **ProcessID** (Foreign Key to ProcessTable) ...