# Should there be 2 datatables for a Parent and Child class in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, database, inheritance

I have two classes `Parent` and `Child`.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    private String extraField1;
    private String extraField2;
    ...
}
```

`Child` class has 2 extra fields `extraField1` and `extraField2`.

Q1. Should I make two diff. tables in the databse: one for `Child` and other for `Parent`?

or

Q1. Should I add two columns in the `Parent` table (each column for one extra field) and  store the `Child` in the `Parent` table.

=============================== EDITED =======================================

Yes, `Child` and `Parent` are classes in the same hierarchy.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve? What are those `extraField1/2`? Basicly in lots of cases `Parent` and `Child` are the same thing - they are certain elements of some hierarchical structure.

Comment: I don't understand your basic concept. Why does a Child *extend* the parent? This is not the normal way of treating 1:n relationships, unless Java does it way differently than the OOP languages I know.

Comment: Anyway, as I already said in the other question, I think you definitely need two tables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should there be 2 datatables for a Parent and Child class in Java?

There is no universal answer to this question. There are actually several techniques to map an inheritance hierarchy into a relational database and they all have advantages and disadvantages. Choosing one or the other depends on your context.

Scott Ambler details the various approaches in the section [2. Mapping Inheritance Structures](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MappingInheritance) of his famous paper [Mapping Objects to Relational Databases: O/R Mapping In Detail](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html) that I'm quoting below:

> (...) In this
>   section you’ll see that there are
>   three primary solutions for mapping
>   inheritance into a relational
>   database, and a fourth supplementary
>   technique that goes beyond inheritance
>   mapping.  These techniques are:
>
> - [Map the entire class hierarchy to a single table](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MapHierarchyToTable)
> - [Map each concrete class to its own table](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MapConcreteClassToTable)
> - [Map each class to its own table](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MapEachClassToTable)
> - [Map the classes into a generic table structure](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MapToGenericStructure)

For a full comparison (with advantages, disadvantages and a recommendation on when to use), have a look at the section [2.6 Comparing The Strategies](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#ComparingTheStrategies).

I can't do a better job than him so there is no point at paraphrasing him, just refer to the original paper.

Comment: @Yatendra You're welcome. Glad you find this answer useful (the mentioned essay is actually a must read).

Answer (score 0):

[Patterns of Enterprice Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) covers this as well in its chapters on [Single-table inheritance](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-321-12742-0/ch12lev1sec7), [Class-table inheritance](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-321-12742-0/ch12lev1sec7#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTAtMzIxLTEyNzQyLTAvY2gxMmxldjFzZWM4JmltYWdlcGFnZT0=), and [Concrete-table inheritance](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-321-12742-0/ch12lev1sec7#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTAtMzIxLTEyNzQyLTAvY2gxMmxldjFzZWM5JmltYWdlcGFnZT0=).

The coverage is similar to what Pascal has said. There's no One True Way, but the book does give you a good breakdown of costs and benefits, e.g.

> **The strengths of Concrete Table Inheritance are:**
>
> - Each table is self-contained and has no irrelevant fields. As a result
>     it makes good sense when used by other
>     applications that aren't using the
>     objects.
> - There are no joins to do when reading the data from the concrete
>     mappers.
> - Each table is accessed only when that class is accessed, which can
>     spread the access load.
>
> **The weaknesses of Concrete Table Inheritance are:**
>
> - Primary keys can be difficult to handle.
> - You can't enforce database relationships to abstract classes.
> - If the fields on the domain classes are pushed up or down the hierarchy,
>     you have to alter the table
>     definitions. You don't have to do as
>     much alteration as with Class Table
>     Inheritance (285), but you can't
>     ignore this as you can with Single
>     Table Inheritance (278).
> - If a superclass field changes, you need to change each table that has
>     this field because the superclass
>     fields are duplicated across the
>     tables.
> - A find on the superclass forces you to check all the tables, which leads
>     to multiple database accesses (or a
>     weird join).